# Getting inconsistent results from Github with Python

Tags: python, github-api

See my (new to python code) idea is to get the stars for each programming language and plot them.

Simple python - just iterate over the results from the API and sort the results and then just take the top result as the highest.

I have tested this and the issue is that I keep getting inconsistent results for final "java"

see results after the code block

```
import requests
from plotly import offline

# get all the urls
urls = {'python': 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars',
        'c': 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:c&sort=stars',
        'ruby': 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:ruby&sort=stars',
        'java': 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:java&sort=stars'}

# space for all the stars
python_stars = []
c_stars = []
ruby_stars = []
java_stars = []

headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}

# open the urls and populate the respective lists
for url in urls.values():
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(f"Status Code: {r.status_code}")
    response_dict = r.json()

    repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

    for repo_dict in repo_dicts:

        if repo_dict.get('language') == 'Python':
            python_stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])
        elif repo_dict['language'] == 'C':
            c_stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])
        elif repo_dict['language'] == 'Ruby':
            ruby_stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])
        elif repo_dict['language'] == 'Java':
            java_stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])

# sort for  the top stars
python_stars.sort(reverse=True)
c_stars.sort(reverse=True)
ruby_stars.sort(reverse=True)
java_stars.sort(reverse=True)

# get the top scores
top_python = python_stars[0]
top_c = c_stars[0]
top_ruby = ruby_stars[0]
top_java = java_stars[0]

langs = ['python', 'c', 'ruby', 'java']
top_stars = [top_python, top_c, top_ruby, top_java]

data = [{
    'type': 'bar',
    'x': langs,
    'y': top_stars,
    'marker': {
        'color': 'rgb(255,100,150)',
        'line': {'width': 1.5, 'color': 'rgb(25,25,25)'}
    },
    'opacity': 0.9

}]

my_layout = {
    'title': 'Most Starred  Projects on GitHub for Python, C, Ruby, Java',
    'titlefont': {'size': 28},
    'xaxis': {
        'title': 'Repo',
        'titlefont': {'size': 24},
        'tickfont': {'size': 14},
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'title': 'Stars',
        'titlefont': {'size': 24},
        'tickfont': {'size': 14},
    }
}

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='toplangstars.html')`
```

the results that I have had are

> Run 1 P = 109 C = 99 R = 46 J = 90
>
> Run 2 P = 109 C = 99 R = 46 J = 43
>
> Run 3 P = 109 C = 99 R = 46 J = 112
>
> Run 4 P = 109 C = 99 R = 46 J = 112
>
> Run 5 P = 109 C = 99 R = 46 J = 90

Comment: I don't seem to see a fault on your side. Have you tried to output the raw json, and check if the results are different. If so, then you know that it wasn't any parsing issues

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass user and token to authenticate github?

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}
username = 'your user name'
token = 'your token'

# open the urls and populate the respective lists
for url in urls.values():
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers,auth=(username,token))
```

Only update this part of your code. If you don't have a user and token you can get it from [here](https://github.com/settings/developers) by creating a github app.

With this, I tried several times and got the same result.